# Moving style property from div element

Tags: html, css

I have the following div with style:

`<div class="icon red" style="flex: 0.8">`
If I want to move the style from the div attribute , is this the correct way:

```
    <div class="iconred">
      <style>
        div.iconred {
          flex: 0.8;
        }
      </style>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is correct as well but it isn't necessary to place the `style` in the `div` you want to style, it can be anywhere on the page. Ideally should be in a separate stylesheet or in the head of the HTML

Comment: the selector should be `div.icon.red` as the class is `icon` and `red` not `iconred`

Comment: You can check the [basic rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics) of using CSS for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="icon red" style="flex: 0.8">`

That div has two different classes: `icon` and `red`.

In CSS you used `div.iconred` which indicates an element with a single class, the class `iconred`.

So you actually should use `div.icon.red` as it then looks for a div element with both the classes `icon` and `red`.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    div.icon.red {
      flex: 0.8
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="icon red"></div>
</body>
```

The `<style>` tag has to be always placed within the head element. With the deprecation of the scope attribute, it is no longer valid to place it within the body.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct, if you want to add style to an element, you have options:

**Inline style** like how you do first,

**Internal style** defined in the  section of an HTML page, within a `<style>` element.

**External style** add a link to it in the `<head>` section of HTML page

In your case you want to use `Internal style` so you have to move your `style` element to the `<head>` section.

The correct way:

```
<head>
 <style>
      div.iconred {
         flex: 0.8;
      }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="iconred">
          
    </div>
</body>
```

Read more in [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Comment: .iconred is not the class that is being used. Two classes are being used. This answer is incorrect.